# I want to highlight RED the timeslot that is already in the array clickedDateTime

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile

When I click "SELECT ALL BUTTON", I want to highlight all currently shown buttons.

The desired timeslots are already in `clickedDateTime`

Console Log

[image: 1]

but the buttons of timeslots are not changing color to red as I intended to

Problem:

[image: 2]

expected output(I want it to be like this):

[image: 3]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hoopers/widgets/textTheme.dart';

class RegistrationCalendarScheduling extends StatefulWidget {
  List clickedDateTime;
  int currentMonth = 0; // load current month
  int currentDay = 0; // load current day

  int currentAddYear = 0;
  int currentAddMonth = 0;
  int currentAddDay = 0;
  RegistrationCalendarScheduling(this.clickedDateTime, {Key? key}) : super(key: key){
    var now = DateTime.now();
    currentMonth = now.month-1;
    currentDay = now.day-1;

    currentAddYear = now.year;
    currentAddMonth = now.month;
    currentAddDay = now.day;
  }

  List months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  List days = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'];

  //implement disabled property for buttons?
  List time = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

  //Dummy Data [API] : These are the schedules already taken.
  //TO DO: Create a function that checks if the schedule is already taken

  List currentClicked = [];
  @override
  _RegistrationCalendarSchedulingState createState() => _RegistrationCalendarSchedulingState();
}

class _RegistrationCalendarSchedulingState extends State<RegistrationCalendarScheduling> {

  int dateChecker (int currentMonth) {
    if (currentMonth == 1) {
      return 28;
    }
    else if (currentMonth == 3 || currentMonth == 5 || currentMonth == 8 || currentMonth == 10 ) {
      return 30;
    }
    else {
      return 31;
    }
  }

  String format (int item) {
    if (item+1 < 10) {
      return ("0"+(item+1).toString());
    }
    return((item+1).toString());
  }

  Future<void> _selectAllTime() async {
    var year = widget.currentAddYear;
    var month = format(widget.currentMonth);
    var day = format(widget.currentDay);
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.time.length; i++) {
      String date = year.toString() +
          "-" + month.toString() +
          "-" + day.toString() +
          "-" + widget.time[i].toString();
      // log(date);

      if (! widget.clickedDateTime.contains(date)) {
        widget.clickedDateTime.add(date);
        // String item;
        // String clickedDateTime;
        // List clickedDates;
        calendarTimeButton(widget.time[i].toString(), date, widget.clickedDateTime).isClicked(widget.clickedDateTime, date);
        // this.isClicked(clickedDates, date);
        // RegistrationCalendarScheduling(const []).clickedDateTime!.add(date);
      } else {
        widget.clickedDateTime.remove(date);
      }
    }
    // setState(() {
    //   calendarTimeButton(widget.time.toString(),
    //     '',
    //     widget.clickedDateTime!,
    //     widget.currentYear,
    //     widget.currentAddMonth,
    //     widget.currentAddDay,
    //   ).addAllTime(widget.clickedDateTime!);
    // });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp, color: Colors.red),
                onPressed:(){
                  widget.currentMonth == 0? widget.currentMonth = 0 : setState((){
                    widget.currentMonth -=1;
                    widget.currentDay = 0;
                  });
                  widget.currentAddMonth == 0? widget.currentAddMonth = 0 : setState((){
                    widget.currentAddMonth -=1;
                    widget.currentDay = 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
              textTheme(widget.months[widget.currentMonth], 25, Colors.red, 'ZingRust'),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp, color: Colors.red),
                onPressed:(){
                  widget.currentMonth == 11? widget.currentMonth = 11 : setState((){
                    widget.currentMonth +=1;
                    widget.currentDay = 0;
                  });
                  widget.currentAddMonth == 11? widget.currentAddMonth = 11 : setState((){
                    widget.currentAddMonth +=1;
                    widget.currentDay = 0;
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: widget.days.sublist(0, dateChecker(widget.currentMonth)).map((item) =>
              widget.currentDay == widget.days.indexOf(item) ? InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 10, 10),
                      child: textTheme(item, 17, Colors.red, 'PoppinsRegular')
                  )
              ) : InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      widget.currentDay = widget.days.indexOf(item);
                      widget.currentAddDay = widget.days.indexOf(item);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 10, 10),
                      child: textTheme(item, 17, Colors.black, 'PoppinsRegular')
                  )
              )
              ).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: widget.time.sublist(0,4).map((item) => calendarTimeButton(item.toString(), "2022-"+ format(widget.currentMonth) + "-"+format(widget.currentDay)+"-"+item.toString(), widget.clickedDateTime)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: widget.time.sublist(4,8).map((item) => calendarTimeButton(item.toString(), "2022-"+format(widget.currentMonth)+ "-"+format(widget.currentDay)+"-"+item.toString(), widget.clickedDateTime)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: widget.time.sublist(8,12).map((item) => calendarTimeButton(item.toString(), "2022-"+format(widget.currentMonth)+"-"+format(widget.currentDay)+"-"+ item.toString(), widget.clickedDateTime)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: widget.time.sublist(12,16).map((item) => calendarTimeButton(item.toString(),"2022-"+format(widget.currentMonth)+"-"+format(widget.currentDay)+"-"+ item.toString(), widget.clickedDateTime)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
            child: MaterialButton(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                minWidth: double.infinity,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                onPressed: _selectAllTime,
                child: const Text(
                  "Select All",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: 'ZingRust',
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//pass a function that would get the current time, day, and month when button is clicked.
class calendarTimeButton extends StatefulWidget {
  String item;
  String clickedDateTime;
  List clickedDates;

  calendarTimeButton(this.item,this.clickedDateTime, this.clickedDates, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  bool isAvailable(){
    // for(int i=0; i<availableDates.length; i++){
    // if(availableDates[i]['sched'] == clickedDateTime && availableDates[i]['availability'] == "-1"){
    return true;
    // }
    // }
    // return false;
  }

  bool isClicked (List clickedDates, String newClickedDate) {
      return clickedDates.contains(newClickedDate);
  }

  bool check (List clickedDates, String newClickedDate) {
    return clickedDates.contains(newClickedDate);
  }

  void deleteClickedDate(List clickedDates, String newClickedDate){
    if(clickedDates.contains(newClickedDate)){
      clickedDates.remove(newClickedDate);
    }
  }

  void addClickedDate(List clickedDates, String newClickedDate){
    clickedDates.add(newClickedDate);
  }

  @override
  State<calendarTimeButton> createState() => _calendarTimeButtonState();
}

class _calendarTimeButtonState extends State<calendarTimeButton> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.19,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (widget.isAvailable()) {
              widget.isClicked(widget.clickedDates, widget.clickedDateTime)
                  ? widget.deleteClickedDate(
                      widget.clickedDates, widget.clickedDateTime)
                  : widget.addClickedDate(
                      widget.clickedDates, widget.clickedDateTime);
            }
          });
        },
        child: Card(
          // widget.clickedDates, widget.clickedDateTime
          color: widget.isAvailable()
              ? (widget.clickedDates.contains(widget.clickedDateTime)
                  ? Colors.red
                  : Colors.white)
              : Colors.grey[500],
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: textTheme(
                  widget.item + ":00", 13, Colors.black, 'PoppinsRegular')),
          elevation: 5,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel so embarassed now. I just change line 200 to

```
onPressed: () {
   setState(() {
      _selectAllTime();
   });
},
```